# обновление pip через pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pip

Ситуация такая - в папке site-packages находится две версии pip: 10 и 18. PyCharm цепляет 10. При попытке обновить через PyCharm, выдаёт ошибку:

> Collecting pip==18.0
>     Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping
>   Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping
>   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
>   status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed
>   certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/pip/    No
>   matching distribution found for pip==18.0

Удаление 10ой версии из папки также не помогает, как и python setup.py setup (всё устанавливается, но PyCharm по прежнему его не видит)

Comment: А яка в тебе ОС?Windows чи Ubuntu?

Comment: Windows 7 x64 /