# PyCharm и IDLE не видят модуля

Tags: python, pyqt5, pycharm

При попытке импортировать модуль PyCharm подчёркивает "QWidgets". Переименование в  "QtWidgets" не помогает. Выдаёт ошибку:

> ```
> AttributeError: module 'PyQt5' has no attribute 'QWidgets'
> ```

IDLE выдаёт:

> ```
> ImportError: cannot import name 'QWidgets' from 'PyQt5' 
>    (C:\Users\emedyanik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\PyQt5\__init__.py)
> ```

[image: Модуль загружен]

Также пробовала вариант с

```
from PyQt5.uic.Compiler.qtproxies import QtWidgets
```

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.uic'
> ```

Comment: `import PyQt5.QtWidgets`

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'

Comment: Ошибка означает что pyqt5 не установлен. Какая версия питона? Питон один установлен? Как устанавливали pyqt5?

Comment: 3.7. Да, один. Устанавливала через 
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pyqt5
так как просто через pycharm и через pip выдавало ошибку установки

Comment: пишите @gil9red, чтобы мне пришло уведомление о комментарии :) `pip install pyqt5` показывает ошибку? Какую? У меня есть подозрение, что 3.7 еще может не поддерживается, у меня pyqt5 работает на 3.6, поэтому если что, понадобится поставить версию поменьше

Comment: @gil9red Сейчас пишет,что пакет уже установлен.Если попробовать установить неустановленный модуль,вот такая штука
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/numpy/

No matching distribution found for numpy
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: @gil9red задавала вопрос насчёт обновления pip https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869896/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-pip-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-pycharm?noredirect=1#comment1409139_869896
Сейчас в командной строке при проверке версии выдаёт 18, а в pycharm написано, что 10.

Comment: @gil9red удалила папку с pip10, теперь в pycharm pip18. Но библиотеки всё равно невозможно установить Ошибка та же.

Comment: Вы про эту ошибку `"Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, ..."`?

Comment: @gil9red да, она

Comment: Какая-то ошибка сети... с установкой она не связана и из-за нее и нельзя скачать pyqt5 и установить. Можно попробовать добиться установки через сеть или скачать pyq5 https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5 и установить его вручную. Интересно, а `pip install certifi` проходит у вас?

Comment: @gil9red вполне возможно, что вы правы, так как у меня ограниченный доступ к сети, но вот обходными путями удалось установить, однако вот не работает. не, не проходит.

Comment: `"но вот обходными путями удалось установить, однако вот не работает"`, т.е. вы скачали и вручную установили через pip и оно не работает? А какая ошибка была?

Comment: @gil9red если устанавливать вручную, то pycharm вообще его не видит. когда устанавливала так:  pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pyqt5 , то хотя бы видел.

Comment: Вы устанавливаете в сам питон, в его папку. pip в этом случае знает где он находится, а находится в папке питона. Сам pycharm никаких библиотек не имеет, но он знает с каким питоном работает и из его папки собирает список модулей. Попробуйте открыть питон в консоли и введите `import PyQt5`. Если ничего после этого не будет написано, значит модуль импортирован без ошибок. Например у меня: `Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5
>>>`

Comment: @gil9red в idle ничего не выдаёт, то есть импортируется без ошибок. Если попробовать import PyQt5.QtWidgets, то выдаёт вот это:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import PyQt5.QtWidgets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'

Comment: Непонятно... я бы попробовал на питон 3.6 откатиться и на него установить. А ругается на `from PyQt5 import Qt`? Кст, а вы слышали про анаконду -- это питон с набором установленных модулей, у него есть дистрибутив собранных модулей

Comment: @gil9red да, подумываю её установить. позже отпишусь, решило ли это проблему.

Comment: gil9red в анаконде такие же проблемы